# Another interrogation about cannot borrow `x` as mutable more than once at a time error

Tags: rust

Considering the following code :

```
struct Foo {
    x: i32,
}

struct Test {
    foos: Vec<Foo>,
    v: i32,
}

fn bar(test: &mut Test, foo: &mut Foo){
    // make something with test
    foo.x = 42;
}

fn main() {
    let test = &mut Test {
        foos: vec![
            Foo {x: 3}, 
            Foo {x: 4},
        ], 
        v: 55
    };

    // First time test got borrowed
    let iterator = test.foos.iter_mut();

    for elem in iterator {
        // !!Error second time test got borrowed as mutable
        bar(test, elem);
    }

}
```

Supposing I can't change its signature, Is there a way to call `bar` in the loop for each element of `test.foos` without violating the only one `&mut` at a time rule?

The ony solution I can think of is to clone test before it got borrowed as mutable the first time, as in:

```
let mut tutu = test.to_owned();
let iterator = test.foos.iter_mut();

for elem in iterator {
    bar(&mut tutu, elem);
}
```

but cloning a struct feels like possibly expensive operation depending of the struct.

Comment: Can I ask why you can't change the function signature? That seems like you're shutting the door on potential solutions and creates something of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) in my opinion. I understand your example is stripped down to the basics but without knowing more, it seems strange to require the mutability of both a child and its parent in the same function signature (in this particular small example). Perhaps you could pass the parent or just the child with a `Result` that the caller can act on?

Comment: In order to push for rust, I decided to rewrite a library of which the design has already been decided ([sendsecure-*](https://github.com/xmedius/)) and I wanted to keep kind of the same homogeneity than in the other languages. I'm doing something similar than [this](https://github.com/xmedius/sendsecure-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/xmedius/sendsecure/Client.java#L234) in Java. Here, `uploadAttachment()` is the `bar()` function I wrote in the above example.

Comment: If I may make a bold claim (having looked quickly at the Java sample you linked to) - your _actual_ use case does not require that the parent be mutable. `uploadAttachment` in your linked GitHub source only ever calls `getUploadUrl` on the `safebox`. I would say translating this to Rust should be straight forward, in that you can pass the URL in separately without doubling the mutable reference.

Answer (score 0):

The GitHub Java example you linked to doesn't actually require that the parent and child both be mutable. In fact, the parent (in your Java, this is the `safebox`) only ever calls `getUploadUrl()`.

As such, I have translated it slightly into Rust for you with similar type names to your Java example. The idea being that the method itself only cares about the URL ... so pass it in directly rather than taking a mutable reference:

```
struct Attachment {
    guid: String,
}

impl Attachment {
    fn new<S>(guid: S) -> Attachment
        where S: Into<String>
    {
        Attachment { guid: guid.into() }
    }

    fn set_guid<S>(&mut self, guid: S)
        where S: Into<String>
    {
        self.guid = guid.into();
    }
}

struct SafeBox {
    attachments: Vec<Attachment>,
    upload_url: &'static str,
}

impl SafeBox {
    fn get_upload_url(&self) -> &str {
        self.upload_url
    }
}

fn uploadAttachment(upload_url: &str, attachment: &mut Attachment) {
    attachment.set_guid("12345");
}

fn main() {
    let mut safebox = SafeBox {
        attachments: vec![Attachment::new("12345"), Attachment::new("67890")],
        upload_url: "http://upload.com/upload",
    };

    for mut attachment in &mut safebox.attachments {
        uploadAttachment(safebox.upload_url, &mut attachment);
    }
}
```

Here it is [running in the playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=dc55c96d4aec6577c715c660a0106a3b&version=stable).

As someone who has tried porting a simple C# library to Rust, I can tell you from experience it is a bad idea to try and port it line-for-line, type-for-type. The Rust Way (tm) is very different and C# (or Java) simply can't be ported directly.

Comment: Yes, I understand this is a bad idea to try to port the code line-for-line. But with the "inside-of-the-box" being different, the goal was for me to try to provide the same API for homogeinity. The reason why the signature of `uploadAttachment()` was as is, is because of `submitSafebox(&mut safebox)` which require a mutable borrow because of the [call to] (https://github.com/xmedius/sendsecure-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/xmedius/sendsecure/Client.java#L232) `initializeSafebox(&mut safebox)`. But you're right, giving `uploadAttachment` the url may be the most normal thing to do.